# iframe in Salesforce Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-apps, lightning-web-components

I am showing a site inside an iframe using lightning web components. I've successfully gotten it to show but sometimes the page has to be reloaded for the content to show in the iframe. I have also noticed that this is only the case for Chrome, it seems to be working fine in Safari.

This is what I have tried based on [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work) to reload the iframe.

In my Javascript file I have this:

```
 get fullUrl() {
    let iframe = this.template.querySelector('iframe');
    iframe.reload(); 
    return `https://my-sitename.com/amazon/customer_system_api.php?token=XVF1C5CGE&sys=${this.sysId}&type=header`;
}
```

And my html file is simply this:

```
<template>
<lightning-card  title="System Information" icon-name="custom:custom59">
    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <iframe width="800" height="400" src={fullUrl}></iframe>
    </div>    
</lightning-card>
```

But I am getting the following error in "Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.template.querySelector"

I'm new to Salesforce, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: are you refreshing on button click?

Comment: when the page loads @Pranay

Comment: Is the issue that my-sitename.com doesn’t always return a good response or that the iframe in lwc has an issue?

Comment: @KevinVenkiteswaran  I have to refresh the page for the iframe to load.

Answer (score 2):

Quite tricky. I managed to get it done by using `onload` event of iframe. Whenever iframe finishes its loading ,it calls `onload` event. I wrote a listener for `onload` event in `renderedCallback` method that will call it to reload it , if its first time load.

I am maintaining state using `isReloaded` variable in JS

Markup :

```
<template>
<lightning-card  title="System Information" icon-name="custom:custom59">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <iframe width="800" height="400" src={fullUrl}></iframe>
        </div>    
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS COde:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {

    @api sysId = '202';
    theIframe;

    get fullUrl() {

    return `https://my-sitename.com/amazon/customer_system_api.php?token=XVF1C5CGE&sys=${this.sysId}&type=header`;
    }

    @api isReloaded = false;


renderedCallback() {
    console.log('rendred callback called' + this.theIframe);
        if(this.theIframe==undefined){
            this.theIframe =  this.template.querySelector('iframe');
            this.theIframe.onload = ()=>{
                console.log('Onload called'+this.isReloaded);

                if(!this.isReloaded){
                    this.isReloaded = true;
                    this.theIframe.src = this.theIframe.src ;

                }
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

Playground Link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/dFVcvXbqK/3/edit (Iframe wont load in playground due to CORS, but you can see console debugs showing the working logic)

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233928/iframe-onload-javascript-event

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86428/what-s-the-best-way-to-reload-refresh-an-iframe

Comment: renderedCallback() is invoked on every render so you do *not* want to attach an event listener in it without some type of guard.

Comment: Thanks @KevinVenkiteswaran for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You should not refer iframe element in fullUrl method as this method is called on iframe itself.

You need only url from fullUrl method so only return url like this.

```
get fullUrl() {
    return `https://my-sitename.com/amazon/customer_system_api.php?token=XVF1C5CGE&sys=${this.sysId}&type=header`;
}
```

**Modified code:** 
You should use renderedCallback to update url in fullUrl variable. This will reflect in iframe.

```
         @track fullUrl
         renderedCallback()
         {
             this.fullUrl=`https://my-sitename.com/amazon/customer_system_api.php?token=XVF1C5CGE&sys=${this.sysId}&type=header`;
         }
```

Comment: How would I do iframe.reload(); ?

Comment: How are you reloading it? any event to trigger reload?

Comment: iframe will show with URL automatically. Do you want to load on any event?

Comment: I'm trying to force reload the iframe on load

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni in the HTML I have src={fullUrl}. Is it still correct?

Comment: If I am not wrong, renderedCallback will be called even before  the iframe loaded the frame for the first time?